# Map two arrays in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays
The first array

```
{
    "heart_rate": 27,
    "height": 82,
    "weight":78
}
```

The second array

```
[
    {
    "id": "heart_rate",
    "description": "le ratio coeur",
    "label":"ratio coeur"
    },
    {
        "id": "height",
        "label": "taille",
        "description": "la taille"
    },
    {
        "id": "weight",
        "label": "poids",
        "description": "le poids"
    }
]
```

can I use `map` function to match the key of the first array and the id of the second array in order to get a result array like this

```
[
{
 "label": "poids",
 "value": 82,
 "description": "le poids"
},
{
 "label": "taille",
 "value": 78,
 "description": "la taille"
},
{
 "label": "ratio coeur",
 "value": 27,
 "description": "le ratio coeur"
},
]
```

Comment: You "first array" is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: can't use map function on an object ?

Comment: No, it's an array operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MGX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20059754/mgx) is correct. Your first item is **not** an array but an object.

This is what you got to do, to make it work with an object.

```
const valueObject = {
    "heart_rate": 27,
    "height": 82,
    "weight":78
};

const array = [
    {
        "id": "heart_rate",
        "description": "le ratio coeur",
        "label":"ratio coeur"
    },
    {
        "id": "height",
        "label": "taille",
        "description": "la taille"
    },
    {
        "id": "weight",
        "label": "poids",
        "description": "le poids"
    }
]

const keys = Object.keys(valueObject);
const values = Object.values(valueObject);

const result = array.map((item) => { 
  return {
    label: item.label,
    value: values[keys.findIndex(key => key === item.id)],
    description: item.description,
  };
});
```

Alternatively you can convert your `valueObject` to a `Map` to get the result easier:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(valueObject));

const result = array.map((item) => { 
  return {
    label: item.label,
    value: map.get(item.id),
    description: item.description,
  };
});
```